# Mockito to mock final field of class

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, android-unit-testing

I am trying to mock a final field of class Student

```
data class Student(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val marks: Marks
)

data class Marks(
    val subject1: String
)
```

and this is my test class

```
class StudentTest {

    @Test
    fun testStudentMarks() {
        val student = mock(Student::class.java)
        assertNotNull(student.id)
        assertNotNull(student.marks)
    }

}
```

On running test it passes student.id but it fails on student.marks with the below error

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:55)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:22)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:256)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:248)
    at com.example.mockitotest.StudentTest.testStudentMarks(StudentTest.kt:16)
```

How can I mock marks field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a `Kotlin` class, you can just do

```
Mockito.when(student.id).thenReturn(0)
```

or

```
val m = Mockito.mock(Marks::class.java)
Mockito.when(student.marks).thenReturn(m)
```

Comment: But for java `when` requires only method call. As a solution can be add additional getter for final veriable.

Comment: But `student.id` in java anyway will look like `student.getId()`, isn't it?

Comment: @Demigon right, but the question is how to mock final field without getter. For example how to mock value for this `final` integer in Student java class: 
    ```class Student { public final int id = 10; }```

Comment: Yeah. An additional getter is good when you can change this class. In case of java things are a bit complicated :)